# MySQL me regresa #1054 - La columna 'materias.id_materia' en where clause es desconocida

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente sentencia:

```
SELECT
    `limite`,
    `nombre_profe`,
    `horario`
FROM
    `materias`
INNER JOIN `profesores` ON `materias.asignaciones` = `profesores.id_profesor`
INNER JOIN `secciones` ON `materias.secciones` = `secciones.id_secciones`
INNER JOIN `horarios` ON `materias.horarios` = `horarios.id_horarios`
WHERE
    `materias.id_materia` = 1
```

Y me marca este error:

> MySQL ha dicho:
>
> 1054 - La columna 'materias.id_materia' en where clause es desconocida

Adjunto mis tablas:

[image: secciones]

[image: profesores]

[image: materias]

Comment: Si la memoria no me falla tiene que ser WHERE `materias`.`id_materia`done los delimitadores son por tabla y por columna

Comment: La columna se llama horario_materia según tus imágenes, no?

Answer (score 3):

Las backticks tienen que estar en función de tabla y luego de columna, el error te esta indicando que busca una columna donde el nombre tiene esto: `tabla.columna` lo cual no existe.

Entonces si tienes la necesidad de seguir usándolas debe quedar así:

```
WHERE `materias`.`id_materia` = 1
```

De esta manera las backticks identifican a la tabla y columna como entes por separado.

Por otro lado considera solamente usar estas comillas simples invertidas solamente cuando vayas a marcar que tienes en tu base de datos una tabla y/o columna cuyos nombres son palabras reservadas del motor de bases de datos y entonces al colocarlo estás evitando una posible alerta donde la herramienta te avise que esa palabra esta reservada.

Dado el caso que nos muestras no se hace necesario su uso pues incluso tus tablas y columnas están en español.

Comment: Pero en el ON (del join) funciona.. eso es por el orden de ejecucion del query?

Comment: Si @gbianchi efectivamente funciona pero basándome en una prueba local y el propio uso de los backticks le hice esta observación

Comment: perdon, de igual forma le quite los backticks, pero me arroja el mismo error en la parte de 'materias.horarios'

Comment: Colocaste en entre las comillas por separado a la tabla y luego a la columna @ErnestoVazquez ?

Comment: Es correcto y tambien probe removiendolos en toda la query

Comment: @BetaM ya esta actualizado, gracias

Comment: Bueno @ErnestoVazquez de acuerdo con las propias imágenes que nos muestras la tabla materias con una columna horarios no existe, la que si existe es: `materias.horario_materia` entonces debería ser esa la columna a invocar es decir: **materias.horario_materia**

Comment: Sí, muchas gracias, no recordaba ese cambio por las prisas.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El error fue no revisar el cambio en el campo de la tabla materia [materias.horario_materia]

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta que te sirvio. Si este fue tu error, seria algo no reproducible o un error tipografico y la pregunta se cerraria...